# Changing the properties of the Tools Palette in LiveCode

Tags: livecode

I inadvertently set all preferences to default in live code 9 and now the width of the Tools Palette is wider (I guess it's three columns wide). I would like to set the width to two columns width.
Also when I start a stack I now see a grey 'background' instead of the desktop. I use MacOS High Sierra on a MacBook Pro and LiveCode 9.0.0.
How can I change these values, since I don't see those items in the Preferences-window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The tools palette width can be set by clicking on the preferences icon in its upper right corner.

The way to fix your "backGround" issue is to select the "backDrop" menuItem in the "View" menu. Your choice will stick between sessions/